# Android SDK: hello world does not run

Tags: android, launch

I have installed Java x64, Eclipse Classic Juno x64 + ADT Pluggin. OS win 7 x64. I  installed everything according to the manual. Then created first application and launched it. Emulator was launched but the hello world app didn't. I have no idea what i am doing wrong. Does anyone know of such error and my problem as a whole? thx

```
Console log:
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - test] ------------------------------
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - test] Android Launch!
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - test] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - test] Performing com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - test] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_41'
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - test] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_41'
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\Zewisa\.android\avd\AVD_41.avd/sdcard.img
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2012-10-06 13:35:42 - Emulator]
```

UPD: I updated audio & video drivers. All the errors have gone, but still application does not launch

UPD2: made some screenshot

[image: run application]

[image: emulator config]

Comment: have you run the app on two emulators at the same time?

Comment: no, i have not. i was trying to do it but no result

Comment: you do not have OpenGL ES support for the emulation and you have a lock on the data on your SD image; as "plus" you are using Windows ...

Comment: I reinstall video and audio drivers. all the errors are gone, but "hello world" still does not launch. what to do?

Comment: Explain in detail and attach a screenshot if you can

Comment: sorry for the delay, attached some screenshot for you. I running an application hoping to see "Hello world" like this http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-9vPquiDj29A/T3Mh0XNFs2I/AAAAAAAAAZw/sYVQgqJX67k/s1600/helloworldandroid.png but nothing happens

Comment: no one has any ideas? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake, I have killed the process adb.exe than launched emulator from AVD Manager when it launched runned application and hello world was runned, thx for everyone

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes app gets installed onto the emulator but it's main activity is not launched. Check the apps on the emulator to see if your app is installed. If it is, try launching it from there